# WCF Ria DateTime http query serialization

Tags: wcf

I need to call a wcf ria domain service and I want to use filtering. I need to code the http url explicitly myself. I found the following example on the net [here](http://jasonharper.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/ria-services-under-the-hood-part-2-query-operations/):

```
https: //..../SnagAllPeeps?$where=(Age%3e35)
```

> This will call SnagAllPeeps such that
>   all returned items have an Age
>   property with a value greater than 35.
>   What I need is to do essentially the
>   same for properties of type DateTime.
>   But how are these serialized? I tried
>   something like:
>
> ```
> https: //..../SnagAllPeeps?$where=(PostedOn%3e0001-01-01T00%3a00%3a00)
> ```

But this does not work. Any idea what the right format is or how I can find out?

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.jsonquerystringconverter.aspx)Hi, the two classes you need here are [QueryStringConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.querystringconverter.aspx) and JsonQueryStringConverter. Hope that helps!